# subprocess with logging module: tee with StringIO

Tags: python, python-2.x, io, logging, child-process

I've got a long-running process. Once it finishes I need the output. But the user should be informed while it's running. With the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module I get timestamps and whatnot preceding. So let's combine all 3:

Prelude:

```
import os
import logging
import subprocess

from io import IOBase
from sys import stdout
from select import select
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

from cStringIO import StringIO
```

Init:

```
# Some other file, like __init__.py
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    level='INFO')
handler = logging.root.handlers.pop()
assert logging.root.handlers == [], "root logging handlers aren't empty"
handler.stream.close()
handler.stream = stdout
logging.root.addHandler(handler)
# Some other file, like __init__.py

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Class (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4838875):

```
class StreamLogger(IOBase, logging.Handler):
    _run = None
    def __init__(self, logger_obj, level):
        super(StreamLogger, self).__init__()
        self.logger_obj = logger_obj
        self.level = level
        self.pipe = os.pipe()
        self.thread = Thread(target=self._flusher)
        self.thread.start()
    def __call__(self):
        return self
    def _flusher(self):
        self._run = True
        buf = b''
        while self._run:
            for fh in select([self.pipe[0]], [], [], 1)[0]:
                buf += os.read(fh, 1024)
                while b'\n' in buf:
                    data, buf = buf.split(b'\n', 1)
                    self.write(data.decode())
        self._run = None
    def write(self, data):
        return self.logger_obj.log(self.level, data)
    emit = write

    def fileno(self):
        return self.pipe[1]
    def close(self):
        if self._run:
            self._run = False
            while self._run is not None:
                sleep(1)
            for pipe in self.pipe:
                os.close(pipe)
            self.thread.join(1)
```

Filtering class (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/41328542):

```
class LevelRangeFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, min_level, max_level, name=''):
        super(LevelRangeFilter, self).__init__(name)
        self._min_level = min_level
        self._max_level = max_level

    def filter(self, record):
        return super(LevelRangeFilter, self).filter(record) and (
            self._min_level is None or self._min_level <= record.levelno) and (
                   self._max_level is None or record.levelno < self._max_level)
```

Usage:

```
stderr_stream = logging.StreamHandler(StringIO())
stderr_stream.addFilter(LevelRangeFilter(logging.ERROR, None))
log.addHandler(stderr_stream)
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

stdout_stream = logging.StreamHandler(StringIO())
stdout_stream.addFilter(LevelRangeFilter(logging.INFO, logging.ERROR))
log.addHandler(stdout_stream)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

with StreamLogger(log, logging.INFO) as out, StreamLogger(log,
                                                          logging.ERROR) as err:
    subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=out, stderr=err, shell=True)

print 'stderr_tee =', stderr_tee.stream.getvalue()
print 'stdout_tee =', stdout_tee.stream.getvalue()
```

With a cleanup like so:

```
# finally block
for handler in log.handlers:
    log.removeHandler(handler)
    handler.stream.close()
    handler.close()
stderr_tee.stream.close()
stdout_tee.stream.close()
```